# Interface Builder doesn't show some of my resource images

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

I have almost 20 images in PNG format added to my current project on Xcode (under the proper group, Resources). Unfortunately, library window's Media tab doesn't show some of them. And if I create an UIImageView and set one of these invisible images from code, nothing shows up. I also tried from IB with adding a UIImageView and set its source image.

Is this problem a image format related issue or is there a tiny detail I'm missing.

What log says:

```
Could not load the "07_clock_icon.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle
```

Comment: I have a vaguely similar problem -- the images won't show up in IB at all. However, if I manually set the image, it works fine (so it's not a problem with PNG format).

Answer (score 7):

The solution to this is a bit silly, but it definitely works:

Close XCode and the Interface Builder. Now, instead of opening XCode then opening the project, navigate to the project in Finder and double click on the project. When you open your xib file the blue file not found images will flash up, then be replaced with the correct images and the dropdown will show all your images in the Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Heyy! I figured it out. It's a refreshing bug. So just copy and replace those images that did not load into your project folder, and then hold Shift Command K (to clean your project). After Clean Up it should work perfectly! Enjoy!

Comment: “copy and replace those images … into your project folder”? Can you clarify your answer, please?

Comment: Sorry, Go into your folder and select the images that didn't load, then copy them onto your desktop for the moment. Go back to Xcode and select the images that didn't load and delete them, and click ALSO MOVE TO TRASH.

Then drag the images you placed on your desktop to the xcode window, and make sure to check the "Copy items into destination group's folder" Then just re-add the new images on Interface Builder, preform the clean up command, and build your project. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you dragged the images from the Finder into the Resources folder in XCode the images should show up in IB as well. At least it does so in my setup.

Maybe the images are 8-bit PNG images. I believe Cocoa requires them to be 24-bit because of the alpha transparency. PNG 8-bit doesn't support the alpha channel, as it's more like a GIF image.

But from the error you posted It seems IB couldn't find the resource at all. Which is understandable if it doesn't load the resources from XCode in its library.

Comment: All of the images are 24-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you selected the option to let XCode copy the files into your project and neither XCode nor the Finder complain when you make the copy... I wonder if there might be some file corruption? Maybe try recreating them or opening and resaving them from another graphics application (or even Preview.app).

btw- 8-bit PNGs have worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was encountered by me. The problem is with the image. The image has been some how corrupted.Try to open the image in photoshop and you will see it doesn't open with photoshop.
I solved the problem by changing the image format to **PNG-24**  and everything works fine for me.
Hope this will solve your issue.

Regards,

Rupesh R Menon