# xcode resource images not found in inspector builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

im implementing an ios program in xcode. i added a imageview onto the view window and i have also added a png 24 bit image to my resource folder. i clicked imageview and in inspector builder->image view->select image dropdown list, its not showing the available images in my resource folder. i have already tried the solutions in [Interface Builder doesn't show some of my resource images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788628/interface-builder-doesnt-show-some-of-my-resource-images) but still not getting it to work.

where am i going wrong??

Comment: have xcode give to you any error when you run?

Comment: nope there are no compilation errors

Comment: so what abt runtime error?

Comment: i realise that when i run the simulator, i couldnt see the textboxes. strange

Comment: i recreate my project and now it works. now sure why. im using xcode 3.2.6 with interface builder

Comment: 3.2.6? Next time please mention that you are a computer archaeologist who wants to figure out how developers built apps in 2010. ;-) Seriously, it's time to upgrade, your app won't make it to the store if it's not developed in Xcode 4.5.